# Write file relative to server's absolute path in node.js

Tags: node.js, path

Does anyone know how I can write a file relative to my server's absolute path: `/var/logs/.../`? Right now I am building my path like: `../../../../var/logs`. I am looking for something like:

`server_root/var/logs`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute paths (`/var/...`), just like any other system that uses paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current execution path of server using rootpath variable

```
var path = require('path'),

var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..'); //_dirname is from nodejs
```

Now you can use this to get exact path of all the directories